# Y coordinate of bottom of frame text on Beamer slide

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I'd like to be able to place things at the top of the white area in this graphic - under the light gray bar that is the "Frame" subtitle text, but touching it. Maximizing the use of the white region. Is there any way to determine that from `textheight` or `frameheight` or some other variables? I've tried to define a new `\bodyheight` variable but have not been successful.

[image]

The graphic above is made with this MWE

```latex
\documentclass[presentation, smaller, compress, aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{seagull}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
\nointerlineskip
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.1cm,wd=\paperwidth,leftskip=.2cm,rightskip=0cm]{frametitle}%
\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}\insertframetitle\\
\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle
\end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\bodyheight}{\textheight - \footskip}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\begin{frame}{Frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift=(current page.south west)] 
    \draw[help lines,line width=1pt,step=1,black!50] (0,0) grid (20,\bodyheight);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: have a look -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/558474/197451

Comment: Hmmm.... That answer is negatively rated and all comments say "not helpful". I don't see how it helps me get the specific coordinates of the white/light-gray transition on by Beamer slide. Please clarify here if I'm missing something...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [tikzpagenodes](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes) package. It provides various nodes such as `current page text area`. For example, using this to draw a line from `(current page text area.north west)` to `(current page text area.north east)` gives almost what you want:

[image]

For completeness, here is the code:

```
\documentclass[presentation, smaller, compress, aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{seagull}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
\nointerlineskip
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.1cm,wd=\paperwidth,leftskip=.2cm,rightskip=0cm]{frametitle}%
\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}\insertframetitle\\
\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle
\end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\newcommand{\bodyheight}{\textheight - \footskip}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\begin{frame}{Frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift=(current page.south west)]
    \draw[help lines,line width=1pt,step=1,black!50] (0,0) grid (20,\bodyheight);
    \draw[blue, thick](current page text area.north west)--(current page text area.north east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**
In the comments it is said that:

> I'm looking for the line below "Frame", not above "Frame".

The point of using [tikzpagenodes](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes) is that it is not hard to get from the top of the page to the top of the frame. For example, we can get:

[image]

using

```
\documentclass[presentation, smaller, compress, aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{seagull}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
\nointerlineskip
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.1cm,wd=\paperwidth,leftskip=.2cm,rightskip=0cm]{frametitle}%
\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}\insertframetitle\\
\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle
\end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\newcommand{\bodyheight}{\textheight - \footskip}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\begin{frame}{Frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift=(current page.south west)]
    \draw[help lines,line width=1pt,step=1,black!50] (0,0) grid (20,\bodyheight);
    \draw[blue, thick]([yshift=-4ex]current page text area.north west)--([yshift=-4ex]current page text area.north east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm looking for the line below "Frame", not above "Frame".

Comment: @mankoff Sure, but something like `([yshift=4ex]current page text area.north west)` should give you want you want. See my edit.

Comment: Sure - I can hard code it. I don't need an extra package, I could just set `bodyheight` to 79.3 mm. I was looking for something else...